# how to pass folder path (not installation foler) during installation using setup project

Tags: c#, .net, setup-project

i want to pass the folder path during my application installation where the log file is saved. the file path is save in app.config. how can i customize the installation process to add custom dialog box to pass folder path.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://aspalliance.com/1220_CodeSnip_Editing_WebConfig_File_for_an_Application_using_Visual_Studio_2005) is an example of how to do this.